# Symfony Doctrine disable cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my symfony project I have two entities that are related via one to many.
I need to find the first and last child, so I use repository functions that look like this:

```
public function getFirstPost(Topic $topic)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->addSelect('p')
        ->join('t.posts', 'p')
        ->where('t.id = :topic_id')
        ->setParameter('topic_id' => $topic->getId())
        ->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery();
    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
}
public function getLastPost(Topic $topic)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->addSelect('p')
        ->join('t.posts', 'p')
        ->where('t.id = :topic_id')
        ->setParameter('topic_id' => $topic->getId())
        ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery();
    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

So the only difference is in in `->orderBy()`, for the first Post I use **ASC** and for the last I use **DESC**.

Now If I use one of those functions from my controller, the return the expected result and work just fine. But If I run them both at the same time from my controller, they return the same result, which they shouldn't.

My guess is that Doctrine caches these queries and the results somehow and that's why the return the same so I tried using `$query->useResultCache(false)` but that didn't do anything.

So my question is, why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure there is not only one post in the passed topic?

Comment: Yes, the topic I'm testing on has a first child of Id 17 and a last child of Id 23 and it contains 4 children in total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is cache issue indeed, but mostly it is query issue. Instead of returning a post in these function you return the whole topic with joined posts.

What you can do is to rewrite these queries to select `Post` entity directly and join `Topic` entity to it which will be filtered by.

If you really(dont do this) need these queries to work you can detach first topic returned by one of those methods and then call the other method:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->detach($firstTopic);
```

Comment: Querying for `post` and join `Topic` did the trick. Thank you!